# Using Decodable to get the object and document ID with Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple `User` class which has the following fields:

```
{ 
  "localIdentifier": "xyc9870",
  "isOnline": false,
  "username": "ZS"
}
```

I want to use Swift's `Decodable` to easily turn the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` into a type safe Swift struct. I also want to make sure that I get the `documentID` from the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` for updating the object later.

This is what I'm currently using to decode but obviously it misses the `documentId`

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let localIdentifier: String
    let username: String
    let isOnline: Bool

}
```

Would love a hand here. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote myself a small convenience extension that just brings the `documentID` into the `data` JSON and then I can use the simple `struct` below

```
extension QueryDocumentSnapshot {

    func prepareForDecoding() -> [String: Any] {
        var data = self.data()
        data["documentId"] = self.documentID

        return data
    }

}
```

Decode using:

```
struct User: Decodable {

    let documentId: String
    let localIdentifier: String
    let username: String
    let isOnline: Bool

}

if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, fromJSONObject: doc.prepareForDecoding()) {
    ...
}
```

Edit:

My `JSONDecoder` extension

```
extension JSONDecoder {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, fromJSONObject object: Any) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        return try decode(T.self, from: try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zack, there is no method fromJSONObject of JSONDecoder(). How can you decode it?

Comment: Asif, I just added my extension that allows me to do this