# How to Initialize Firestore Document Reference Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model, google-cloud-firestore, initialization

I have a user model as per the below which gives me a dictionary of a `User`.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol SerializeUser {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any])
}

struct User {
    var documentRef: DocumentReference?
    var displayName: String
    var photoURL: String
    var email: String
    var isEmployee: Bool

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["displayName": displayName, "photoURL": photoURL, "email": email, "isEmployee": isEmployee]
    }
}

extension User: SerializeUser {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard
        let displayName = dictionary["displayName"] as? String,
        let photoURL = dictionary["photoURL"] as? String,
        let isEmployee = dictionary["isEmployee"] as? Bool,
        let email = dictionary["email"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.init(displayName: displayName, photoURL: photoURL, email: email, isEmployee: isEmployee)
    }
}
```

I need to initialize the `documentRef` within my `User` struct somehow any ideas on how to do that? please.

Comment: Why do you want to have the document reference as part of your `User` model? It should be a part of your backend service class.

Comment: I need to access it so that I can store that document reference somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using Decodable Protocol as illustrated in this post;
[Using Decodable to get the object and document ID with Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341137/using-decodable-to-get-the-object-and-document-id-with-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you need an instance of your database to build the document reference.

```
var db: Firestore? = Firestore.firestore()

struct User {
    lazy var documentRef: db.collection("users").document(displayName)
}
```

I don't see a document id referenced anywhere here so I assumed you're using displayName as a key. Declaring the variable as lazy lets you initialize it with your other instance variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the key is the actual DocumentReference class.  But I think I get where you're going with it.